# In JS there is any Pattern or Class style to follow when primarily manipulating DOM Elements?

Tags: javascript, class, design-patterns, coding-style

I'm trying to improve and clean a bit my code that often have this bunch of "**querySelectors**" and **global variables**, so I want to know, there is any pattern or use of Classes in this cases? or just break it in a lot of functions and separate the files is the 'right' thing to do?

this code is just a example of what I mean by "bunch of querySelectors"

```js
    //variables
    const form = document.querySelector("#form_contrato");
    const btnRespAluno = document.querySelector("#label_checkbox_resp_aluno");
    const btnCombo = document.querySelector("#label_check_combo");
    const checkCombo = document.querySelector("#check_combo");
    const cursoSelect = document.querySelector("#curso_nome");
    const select = document.getElementById("curso_nome");
    const comboCurso1 = document.querySelector("#combo_curso_1");
    const comboCurso2 = document.querySelector("#combo_curso_2");
    const valor = document.querySelector("#curso_valor");
    const desconto = document.querySelector("#curso_desconto");
    const total = document.querySelector("#curso_total");
    const comboTextarea = document.querySelector("#combo_textarea");
    const modulos = document.querySelector("#curso_modulos");
    const duracao = document.querySelector("#curso_duracao");
    const parcelas = document.querySelector("#curso_parcelas");
    const vencimento = document.querySelector("#curso_vencimento");
    const fieldsetAluno = document.querySelector("#fieldset_aluno");
    const loadinContrato = document.querySelector("#loading_contrato");
    
    //Listeners
    form.addEventListener("submit", sendForm);
    btnRespAluno.addEventListener("input", checkboxRespAluno);
    btnCombo.addEventListener("input", inputComboCheckbox);
    cursoSelect.addEventListener("change", insertCursoInfo);
    comboCurso2.addEventListener("input", insertComboTextarea);
    valor.addEventListener("input", insertInputValorTotal);
    desconto.addEventListener("input", insertInputValorTotal);
    desconto.addEventListener("change", insertComboTextarea);
    
    //Masks
    VMasker(document.querySelector("#curso_valor")).maskMoney();
    VMasker(document.querySelector("#curso_desconto")).maskMoney();
    VMasker(document.querySelector("#resp_cep")).maskPattern("99999-999");
    VMasker(document.querySelector("#resp_cpf")).maskPattern("999.999.999-99");
    VMasker(document.querySelector("#resp_rg")).maskPattern("99.999.999-S");
    VMasker(document.querySelector("#aluno_rg")).maskPattern("99.999.999-S");
    VMasker(document.querySelector("#aluno_cep")).maskPattern("99999-999");
    
    function insertInputValue(value, target) {
      document.querySelector(target).value = value;
    }

    function insertInputDateValue(...) {
     ...
    }

    
    function replaceToNonBreakSpaceHifen(...) {
     ...
    }

   //and alot of other functions and function calls bellow....
```

Comment: Seems like a number of the queries in `VMasker()` already exist as variables which let you do `VMasker(valor).maskMoney()`. Then a loop approach can be used also for similar ones ... `[valor, desconto].forEach(el => VMasker(el).maskMoney())`

Comment: In this case as I wasn't sure if I should follow the little 'pattern' of the others masks or add this two variables, so ended up  call them as the others, anyway thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, breaking it into modules (or functions/IIFEs) for separate functionalities would be the way to go. You don't need any `class` syntax because you're not creating objects anywhere, and it seems your listeners don't share any state either.

So watch out only for variables that are reused (used in multiple places). For everything else, put the variable, the `addEventListener` call, and the listener declaration together. You might even avoid single-use temporary variables and just write `document.querySelector("…").addEventListener("…", function(event) { … });` as a single statement.

Comment: This was the kind of "assertion" I was looking for. As a self-taught programmer some times I'm not sure if I'm missing something, thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

If you need them, you need them, but it does look unwieldy.  It really depends on your use case. Elements-as-variables can sometimes be accessed dynamically. For example, here's a form with a bunch of values, names, ids and types. Without setting up variables, we can loop through and get their values, tagNames, etc.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  [...e.target.querySelectorAll('input, datalist, select, textarea')].forEach(el => {
    let val = el.value;
    if (['select', 'datalist'].includes(el.tagName.toLowerCase()))  val = el.querySelector('option[selected]').value;
    console.log('tagname: ', el.tagName, 'name: ', el.name, 'id: ', el.id, 'value: ', val);
  })
})
```

```css
label{
display:block;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
<label>Name <input type="text" name="customer_name" value="test value" required>
</label>
<label>Phone <input type="tel"  value="123-123-1234" name="phone_number">
</label>
<label>Email <input type="email" name="email_address"  value="test@value.com" >
</label>
<label>Pickup Date/Time <input type="date"  value="2021-10-02"  name="pickup_time" required>
</label>
<label>Pickup Place <select id="pickup_place" name="pickup_place">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select One</option><option value="office" selected>Taxi Office</option><option value="town_hall" >Town Hall</option><option value="telepathy" >We'll Guess!</option>
</select>
</label>
<label>Dropoff Place <input type="text" name="dropoff_place"  value="test value"  required list="destinations">
</label>
<datalist id="destinations">
<option value="Airport"><option value="Beach">
<option selected value="Fred Flinstone's House">
</datalist>
<label>Special Instructions
<textarea name="comments" maxlength="500">Bring chocolate cake</textarea>
</label>
<button>Submit Booking</button>
</form>
```

Event listener functions can sometimes be consolidated, testing for the listener `event.type` and the target `event.target`. Like the logic for mouseover and mouseout can be combined, like this

```js
const onMO = (e) => {
  console.log('Listener fired for:', e.type, 'on', e.target.tagName, 'with class name', e.target.getAttribute('class'));
}

let m = document.querySelector('.mo');
m.addEventListener('mouseover', onMO);
m.addEventListener('mouseout', onMO)
```

```css
.mo {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class='mo'>Mouse in and out</div>
```

Comment: Despite this wasn't exactly what I was looking for, it still a  very good way get all inputs thanks for sharing it,  in my actual problem doesn't apply because have to do some manipulation with the inputs, but surely I'll use it in other cases, thanks for answer.